# Lua '=' expected near '+'

Tags: lua

I get an error while using the ZeroBrain IDE studio with Lua code.

```
a = 15
a + 2
a ^ 2
math.pi / 4
```

I am new to lua's programming syntax so I am not sure what is wrong with the code. When I run it in the stand-alone interpreter line by line it works fine, but while running it as a chunk I encounter the error in the topic.

Comment: Far from a LUA expert, but I don't think an arbitrary expression (`a + 2`) is valid without assigning the result to something (for example `b = a + 2`)

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out the issue. On the interpreter aka terminal this works fine without having to assign it to a variable. When working with ZeroBrain IDE it doesn't need to be assigned to a variable either but rather contained in a print statement to actually see what it is

Comment: `When working with ZeroBrain IDE it doesn't need to be assigned to a variable either but rather contained in a print statement...`
This is nothing special about ZeroBrane, if you put it into functions (e.g. print) you basically assign it to a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some interactive interpreters (including the one included in ZeroBrane Studio) have two roles: the accept and execute statements, but can also accept and evaluate expressions, which are not valid to be included in Lua code by themselves.

In other words, you can write `if not a then a = 1 end` and then `2*a` in the interpreter (and it should return `2`), but you can't do the same thing in the Lua code (as `2*a` is not a valid statement) and you'll have to write something like `print(2*a)` to make it valid.